# Subreport Inner-join showing different results than same Main report inner-join

Tags: crystal-reports, inner-join

Crystal Reports is used to create templates for another application in my case.  A value is passed from the other application to a specific table, which I can then, in crystal,  use with inner joins to other tables to specify the values on the rest of the report.

This has worked well in situations where I have not being using subreports.  In my main report, I have 4 tables inner joined, and they are correctly being passed a certain value from this program.

My problem lies with attempting to create a coverpage for this particular report.  I needed a detail section on the coverpage, so I looked to creating a subreport on the report header of the main report.  I used the same tables in the subreport itself with the same inner joins.  It receives extra values. This is the exact inner join design with the same tables from the main report, yet it is showing different results.

Does anyone have a solution to this?  I am particularly new to crystal reports, and have just avoided subreports to avoid deeper complication.  I believe I may just be able to pass the criteria value from the main report through a shared variable or parameter as an alternative to my current attempt, but I am not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are taking the right approach by using a subreport. You did add the parameter to the subreport and linked it through from the main report?

I suggest you view the SQL query for both the main report and subreport to identify the discrepancy.